# proving an ODE with a specific solution can't exist using the existence and uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm having trouble completing the following exercise from my homework:

> Let $y'' = f(x, y, y')$ be an ODE that fulfills the criteria for the
> existence and uniqueness theorem ([Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)) in the
> interval [-1, 1].
>
> $y_1(x)$ solves the IVP with initial conditions $y_1(0) = 1$ and
> $y_1'(0) = 0$.
>
> $y_2(x)$ solves the IVP with initial conditions $y_2(0) = 2$ and
> $y_2'(0) = 0$
>
> assume $y_1 \ne$ constant  1.
>
> Prove that a 2nd order ODE that fulfills the criteria for the
> existence and uniqueness theorem so that $y_1(x)\cdot y_2(x)$ is a solution to it within [-1, 1] does not exist.

I'm not very familiar with ODEs, so it might be obvious, but I can't find a way to prove it...

I suspect it involves proving that $y_2(x)$ and $y_1(x)\cdot y_2(x)$ both solve the same ODE and since they have the same initial conditions it forces them to be equal (because of the existence and uniqueness theorem), contradicting the assumption that $y_1 \ne$ constant  1. I can't manage to find the ODE that both of them solve/a way to prove that they both do since I don't know any specific information about the ODEs.

Any help would be very welcome, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the task is reproduced correctly? If you define $g:[-1,1] \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x,y,p):=(y_1y_2)''(x)$, then $g$ is Lipschitz in $y$ and  $p$ with Lipschitz constant $0$ (since $g$ does not depend on $y$ and $p$) and trivially $$(y_1y_2)''(x)=g(x,(y_1y_2)(x),(y_1y_2)'(x))$$ for $x \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: I have copied it word for word, though there very well might be an error in the original question.
wouldn't the ODE you suggested be considered first order though? since it does not involve y''? it will be of the form g(x, y, y') = f(x) which is a first-order ODE...

Comment: No, the ODE is $z''(x)=g(x,z(x),z'(x))$ which is of second order and has the solution $z(x)=y_1(x)y_2(x)$.

Comment: Then there might really be something wrong with the question. 
The existence and uniqueness theorem also requires the function to be continuous in x. Is that guaranteed here? we know y1 and y2 are differentiable twice, but how can we know for sure that their 2nd derivatives are continuous?

Comment: If $y$ is a solution of $y''(x)=f(x,y(x),y'(x))$ then $y$ and $y'$ are continuous (since both are differentiable), and since $f$ is continuous then $y''$ is continuous. Hence $(y_1y_2)''$ is a continuous function on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: yes, I figured that out on my own too a few hours after posting the comment. Thanks a lot, you've been massively helpful!